# CSS Positioning Issue On Mobile Only

Tags: css, position, css-position

I'm having unexpected issue on mobile Safari and Chrome that I can't replicate on the desktop. I was modifying a nav to fixed at the top, but found when I scroll down the footer hides the nav on the mobile browser.

**I recorded an example to show you what I mean:**

What's expected and works on desktop browser (footer slides under nav):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bmUMsfEpauuXx2Jhyf7l2YQrORj6E__z

What happens on mobile Safari and Chrome on iPhone (footer slides on top of nav):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-ri1DqmWPY8hrUP4LaUr-aGpnfH3eVhC

**Site is available here:**
http://michaelespinosa.com/projects/eskimo/index.html

Here is the css for the nav:

```
  #eskimo-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    z-index: 99;
  }
```

Here is the css for the footer:

```
  #eskimo-sidebar {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your website has a lot of problems, especially on mobile. What about the issue you mentioned, try to set `z-index: 10` (or 100) to the element with `eskimo-sidebar` id.

Comment: Hey @sergey-zdobnov, the #eskimo-sidebar element already had a z-index value of 99. I added the css for the nav and footer above. Yes, there are plenty of other issues with this site too!

Comment: @michaelespinosa if honestly, I can't reproduce your problem on emulator. But Anyway your `main` tag also have `position: relative`, try to set z-index for it too + you can remove position relative from footer.

Comment: yeah weird. I made those adjustments but it didn't make a difference. Thanks though